# Stored procedure subquery with 2 column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a stored procedure with 3 parameters that I want to build a report for a Business model, I want to see the best call center from 3 countries, such as France, Germany, Italy I have tried subquery to give alias, but the only problem I am getting when I try to select Country and group by it and any person can see the best Center depending on Country, I need to use 2 column to do that, and give alias for my report, Is there any other approach using AS and Subquery?

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

--@Country Varchar(100) OUTPUT ,
--@Startdate AS DateTIME,
--@EndDate AS Datetime,
--@MinLenght as INT,
--@MaxLenght as INT

--SELECT * FROM VW_FactCallCenter
---SELECt DISTINCT  Date  FROM VW_FactCallCenter

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GET_CallCenterDetail]
    (@Date DateTime,
     @Operator int,
     @Country VARCHAR(7))
AS
BEGIN
    --SELECT @Country = COUNT(Country) FROM VW_FactCallCenter

    SELECT
        (SELECT TotalOperators FROM VW_FactCallCenter WHERE (@Date = Date) and (@Operator = TotalOperators) and (@Country = Country) ) AS TotalOperators,
        (SELECT AVG(ServiceGrade + IssuesRaised WHERE (@Date = Date) and (@Operator = TotalOperators) and (@Country = Country) ) FROM VW_FactCallCenter) AS AvgPointOfCenter,
        (SELECT Max(ServiceGrade), Country 
         FROM VW_FactCallCenter WHERE (@Date = Date) and (@Operator = TotalOperators) and (@Country = Country)
         GROUP BY Country) AS BestCenter
END
```

I get an error:

> Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

My query that gets error is

```
(SELECT MAX(ServiceGrade), Country 
 FROM VW_FactCallCenter 
 GROUP BY Country) AS BestCenter
```

Also I have tried this query but then it does not accept AS like

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT TotalOperators FROM VW_FactCallCenter) AS TotalOperators,
    (SELECT AVG(ServiceGrade + IssuesRaised) FROM VW_FactCallCenter) AS AvgPointOfCenter
FROM 
    VW_FactCallCenter 
WHERE 
    EXISTS (SELECT MAX(ServiceGrade), Country 
            FROM VW_FactCallCenter 
            GROUP BY Country) AS BestCenter
```

DDL

```
CREATE TABLE FactCallCenter (IssuesRaised Smallint, 
                            LevelOneOperators Smallint,
                            LevelTwoOperators Smallint, 
                            ServiceGrade Float, 
                            Shift Nvarchar(20),
                            Date Datetime,
                            TotalOperators Smallint,
                            Country Varchar(7) )


INSERT into FactCallCenter (IssuesRaised, 
                                LevelOneOperators ,
                                LevelTwoOperators , 
                                ServiceGrade , 
                                Shift,
                                Date ,
                                TotalOperators,
                                Country ) VALUES (1,1,4,0.12,'midnight','2014-05-05',5,'Italy');
                                

INSERT into FactCallCenter (IssuesRaised, 
                                LevelOneOperators ,
                                LevelTwoOperators , 
                                ServiceGrade , 
                                Shift,
                                Date ,
                                TotalOperators,
                                Country ) VALUES (2,2,7,0.18,'AM','2014-08-12',9,'France');
```

Comment: `SELECT Max(ServiceGrade), Country....) AS BestCenter` - so which of `Max(ServiceGrade)` *or* `Country` should be returned as the single column `BestCentre`... SQL Server has no idea and they can't both be used, hence your error.

Comment: I need ServiceGrade but also I want to  see which center in countries has the best grade, it should show something like 0.17 France
0.2 Germany
0.21 Italy

Comment: No one should need to guess about your goal. Define "best" in actual words. Then define what resultset you want by supplying a script containing DDL, sample data, and your desired results based on that sample. You want ONE ROW or multiple rows? "Best" implies one. And this `@Date DateTime` has a bad smell - typically reports are based on dates alone and not a very specific point in time within a date. Have you asked your coworkers for guidance? An intern is expected to do - that is one reason for hiring interns.